# How to add table manually on windows azure mobile services DATA>>

Tags: azure, upload, azure-mobile-services

I want to upload table [Excel file] on windows azure Mobile services without coding. Can server side scripting is use for this? Any other option to upload it on Azure Mobile Service Data?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no automatic way to do that. You will need to read your table from the excel file and upload the rows to the server. That should be fairly easy to implement - save your file as a comma-separated value list (or tab-separated value list, which should make parsing easier). In a program which uses the mobile service SDK you'd read the lines from the CSV (or TSV) file, convert it to the appropriate structure (either directly to JSON via the JObject type or a typed class) and call the `InsertAsync` method in the client to insert the data to the server.